How to control data flow?
I'm new to the SDR field and I'm trying to send data that looks like wifi6 signals. I have created OFDM packets using both the ofdm_tx example in GNUradio and the gr-ieee802-11 available on github that I tried to modify in order to increase the number of subcarriers and sending it out on a 20MHz BW using both a B210 and a limeSDR 2.0. After some struggling I think it looks fine :)
Now I would like to control what and when I send. I have tried to read and understand PDUs and streams but I have a bit of hard time to understand how I should start to control the timing and the actual data that is sent. I tried setting up a PDU socket and creating frames from scaPY and sending them out, also used a message strobe. But when I speed it up I got a bunch of
tpb_thread_body :warning: asynchronous message buffer overflowing, dropping message  errors.
Do you have any ideas on how to proceed, a good example I can look at maybe? All pointers are appreciated!
